# Perpendicular bisector in trapezium

Tags: geometry

I am stucked on this problem and I don't know how to solve it.

**THE PROBLEM:**

ABCD - isosceles trapezium (AB || CD)

I have to prove that the bases of ABCD (AB and CD) have got common perpendicular bisector.

I will be very grateful, if someone can help me! :)

Comment: how does an isosceles trapezium different from a normal one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $AD\cap BC=\{E\}$ and $EN$ be a median of $\Delta DEC$.

Thus, since $\measuredangle EDC=\measuredangle ECD,$ we obtain that $ED=EC$ and from here $EN$ is an altitude of $\Delta DEC$.

Also, since $\measuredangle EAB=\measuredangle EBA,$ we obtain that $EA=EB$ and since $EN\perp AB$,

we see that $EN$ is a perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and we are done!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $a$ and $b$ are two parallel lines and if $c$ is orthogonal to $a$ (or $b$) then is $c$ also orthogonal to the other line.

Comment: I think that I understand but I don't know how to start with the solution.

Comment: What I have to write first?